# javascript algorithm - check if record count falls between various number ranges

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that loops through my query depending on a predetermined value. I want to print the query results in, say, 10 records per page. Since my users are going to print double-sided, I want a blank page inserted when total record count is between 21-30, 41-50, 61-70, 81-90, etc.  If total count falls in these ranges that means that the last page my results will be printed on is an odd-numbered page (other than 1) and so I need to insert a blank page so that the next query results are printed on the next odd-numbered page. For example, if total records are between 21-30, these will be printed on 3 pages and need a blank page inserted so that next results are printed starting on page 5. I know the code to insert the blank page but I don't know  the code as to when to insert the blank page.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You should give us some sample data, and your expected output.

Comment: Basically it would look like this:

Comment: if (total#ofrecords is between 21-30 or 41-50 0r 61-70 or 81-90 (or every 20 pages thereafter) then insert a blank page.